# Announcing a Pro Tempore election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Vi and Vim will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://vi.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **September 10, 2018**.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline goes something like this:

- Between now and the start of the nomination period, users can decide whether to nominate themselves and ask questions of candidates on meta. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- During the nomination period, users may nominate themselves and answer any questions that might have been asked on meta.
- At the end of the nomination period, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: How many positions are open?

Comment: One @DJMcMayhem; it's on the right sidebar of the [election page](https://vi.stackexchange.com/election/1).

Comment: Curious about the details here: Is the moderator that comes out of this considered "elected" (for life) or is this a community-driven pro-tem appointment that'll be gone at graduation?

Comment: @Undo: The later.