# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Vi and Vim's [first moderator election](https://vi.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: DJMcMayhem]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking John O'M. who will be stepping down as a moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5680509145317376/0).

Remember this is a [special *pro tempore* election](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election).

Comment: Welcome to the team @DJMcMayhem! It's nice to have you with us!

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to everyone for voting! I'm really grateful for all the support. I'm excited to see what happens next on the site!

Also, thanks to @JohnO'M for his time serving as a mod. :)